# Does Facebook allow send notifications via application sdk?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

Recently I tryed to send an application notification, but i got error:

> (OAuthException) (#2) Failed to create any app request

code is:

```
FacebookClient fbClient = new FacebookClient(access_token);
var args = new Dictionary<string, object>();
args["message"] = "Invitation to app";
args["title"] = "Super title";
args["data"] = "you are welcome";
fbClient.Post("/" + fbid + "/apprequests", args);
```

access_token obtained using:

scope:
**offline_access, publish_stream, user_photos, publish_actions, read_stream, email**

Answer (score 5):

Sending app-generated requests is done with an **application access token**, obtained via the following url: `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=APPID&client_secret=APPSECRET&grant_type=client_credentials`

See [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/channels/#requests)